# R adds not meaningful zeros when loading data

Tags: r

When loading numeric csv data in R, R is adding not meaningful zeros at the end. For example, if my data is

```
set.seed(1234)
original <- sample(1:1000, 6)
original <- as.data.frame(original)
write.csv(original, "temp.csv")
```

When loading data,

```
test <- read.csv("temp.csv")
```

it looks like

```
test <- c(114.00000000, 622.00000000, 
609.00000000, 999.00000000,858.00000000, 638.00000000)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this affect how your program runs? @SurveyStudent88

Comment: @3141 it does not. I can get rid of zeros after a period (.) after loading the data, but I was curious why R is adding meaningless zeros at the end of nuermic vector.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. And it seems strange to me that R writes characters with more zeros and a period. Note that your vector `original` is of class `character`. Besides, `read.csv` reads in objects of class `data.frame` and `test` cannot possibly resemble your posted vector.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi, sorry for the confusion. I edited the question for more clarification. When I read the data, R reads the data as a factor and adds meaningless 8 zeros in the end after a period. R does it to every numeric value that reads as a factor.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it. Now R writes integers to file, I believe that this could only happen if you had doubles in `original`. And as for the second comment of mine, it still holds true, `test` **must** be a `data.frame`.

Comment: I would play with these:  options(encoding="UTF8"); options(digits=22); options(scipen=999)

Comment: Like @RuiBarradas , I cannot reproduce your problem.  I ran your code and when R read your data back into the `test` variable, it just had integers.

Comment: @SurveyStudent88 have you tried to run your code in a fresh R session? If it is still happening there, maybe check your Rprofile.

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos Yes, I think there's an issue with options(), but I can't seem to figure it out. I played with it several times and set as a default, but it still does it

Comment: @kath Yes I did. I had to increase the digit display for another project, and I set up the options again as a default. However, R still adds zeros on those numeric values. When I type options("digits"), it returns "7" which is a default option. I am not sure what is wrong with my R. Is there another way to set up the Rprofile?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem but what does this do?  test <- read.csv("temp.csv", numerals = c("allow.loss"))

Comment: data.frame(sapply(read.csv("temp.csv", as.integer))

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos Sorry about the code. Well, it doesn't work for my data. But thanks. I will play with options(). I increase the digit length for another project earlier, and now I can't seem to reset this as a default.

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos "data.frame(sapply(read.csv("temp.csv", as.integer)) " this line worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
original <- sample(1:1000, 6)
original <- as.data.frame(original)
write.csv(original, "temp.csv")    
data.frame(sapply(read.csv("temp.csv", as.integer))
```